# How to initialize a string object with null value?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, null

Is it possible to initialize `NSString` object with `null` value?
Something like:

```
NSString *strNullTest = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[NSNull null]];
```

When I am doing this it's giving warning:

> instance method -"null" not found return type default to id.

Does anyone knows the right way to initialize a string object with `null`?

Comment: What does a string object w/NSNull even mean?  Do you mean nil?  NSNull is used in collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no "null string" exist in objc. why you want a null string?

either you can use an empty string `@""` or just use `nil`

if you want to put the string in a array or dictionary, `[NSNull null]` is good. all you need to do is to compare the value with `[NSNull null]` fist by `object == [NSNull null]`

Comment: Actually the thing is in my app I am getting (null) string when getting the  NSString *state = [myPlacemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressStateKey]; it is working fine  almost every place but in Israeli state come (null) and my app get crashed but I am not sure null string is the reason for crashing. that is why I want a NULL string for test the app.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize an `NSString` with using the `NSNull` instance.

It's not clear what you want, exactly.  Perhaps you want a nil pointer:

```
NSString *str = nil;
```

`nil` is the same as `NULL`, but we usually use it where an object pointer is required.

Or maybe you want an empty (zero-length) string:

```
NSString *str = @"";
```

This string is a real object (`str != nil`) but contains no characters.

Comment: How to add value to String which was initialised as nil, as when I am trying to assign some value, it still give s nil.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
NSObject *obj1 = @"string";
NSObject *obj2 = [NSNull null];
```

Then to check for null you use  [isKindOfClass:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) method.